# async / await, how to use properly

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to study c# async/await, all the tutorials I found are the same stuff and I can't really understand anything, for instance, why this code doesn't work? Could you please explain the how's and why's of async/await or give some useful links to truly understand given that I don't have experience with it.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Waiter();
        }

        public static async void Waiter()
        {
            await HeavyStuff();
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        }

        public static async Task HeavyStuff()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("2");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213385/discussion-on-question-by-movsar-bekaev-async-await-how-to-use-properly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

await the Waiter() in the Main(). Otherwise it will call Waiter(), but Main() will go on without waiting for Waiter() to finish. That is called "fire and forget". Main() will finish and the program ends before Waiter() is done.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Waiter();
    }

    public static async Task Waiter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await HeavyStuff();
        Console.WriteLine("4"); // this will be instantly shown after "3"
    }

    public static async Task HeavyStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");  // this will be instantly shown after "1"
        await Task.Delay(1000);  // short version of Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))
        Console.WriteLine("3");  // this will be shown after 1 second
    }
}
```

A fire forget version without async Main. In this version we prevent the Main from finishing (= ending the Program) before Waiter can finish.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Waiter();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);  // this gives Waiter() time to finish
    }

    public static async Task Waiter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await HeavyStuff();
        Console.WriteLine("4");
    }

    public static async Task HeavyStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }
}
```

Comment: One important note. You did change the Thread.Sleep to Task.Delay - that is expectable. But the adjective "Heavy" in the method "HeavyStuff" could be dramatically misleading, and I think it needs further explanation. The "asyncness" is not for "Heavy" jobs, like you have to calculate PrimveNumber for big number or anything like this - so it is not designed for CPU intensive jobs. It was designed for IO I/O-bound operations. Of course the rule "Async all the way" causes, that async/await is almost "everywhere" (as normally we do something after querying database)

Comment: that is partially true. You are absolutely right when it comes to non-UI programs like servers. But when we talk about UI-Programs with an UI-Thread, you actually use async await in combination with Task.Run() to get heavy work away from the UI-Thread. It does not make the Program faster, actually it makes it slower. But it feels faster, because the UI-Thread is not blocked and thus the UI is not frozen.

Comment: Totally agree. I didn't say you cannot combined both :) I was only stating the flaw in thinking, that's whenever you need something for HeavyStuff - you bring async/await (i was thinking such way at the very beginning of async/await - missing totally the point)

In the example below, I will rename the method HeavyStuff with IOBoundOperation - to stress out what we want to achieve. It is a very small detail - but the world is built from them ;)

Comment: As a side note, according to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the asynchronous methods should have the suffix `Async`. So the `HeavyStuff` becomes `HeavyStuffAsync` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would urge you to read a [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) by Stephen Cleary for a rather comprehensive explanation of what the point of async/await is.

To your question specifically though, the use of `async` in the method signature prompts the compiler to create a state machine. You must put the `async` keyword in the method in order to enable the use of `await` within the method body (as you likely found when writing `Waiter()` and `HeavyStuff()`).

What ultimately happens here is that when you call Waiter from Main, it does actually call the Waiter method, but because you're not awaiting the result of the call, it treats it as a "fire-and-forget". As such, you experience the program closing.

Similarly, while `Waiter()` awaits `HeavyStuff()` (if Waiter() were awaited from `Main()`), the program will wait for that method to return before showing the "1" on the console.

The blog post above covers this, but you'll likely not want to return void from `Waiter()` because that's typically used for event handling where there's nothing actually waiting on the result of the method. While you're not returning a value with your method, you are awaiting it, so it's better practice to return Task instead.

Since C# 7.1, you've been allowed to use the `async` keyword in your `Main()` entry point, thus your code should be as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Waiter();
    }

    public static async Task Waiter()
    {
        await HeavyStuff();
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }

    public static async Task HeavyStuff()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the link and explanation, did you meant "asynchronous" when writing "but because that's not a synchronous method"? Is this a typo or I am getting confused again

Comment: @MovsarBekaev I've reworded that whole paragraph to hopefully provide a better explanation. In short, by not putting "await", you tell the program not to wait for the result of it and to simply continue executing, which thus closes the program.